# CreateProcess to open program which loads a file

Tags: c++, windows, winapi

I have a situation where I want a program A to open another program B and have program B open a specified file.  I am currently trying to accomplish this by using CreateProcess and passing the file path in the command line arguments.  Here is my code:

```
STARTUPINFO si;
PROCESS_INFORMATION pi;

ZeroMemory( &si, sizeof(si) );
si.cb = sizeof(si);
ZeroMemory( &pi, sizeof(pi) );
CreateProcess("C:\\ProgramB.exe", "C:\\MyFile.txt", NULL, NULL,
              FALSE, 0, NULL, NULL, &si, &pi);
```

What am I doing wrong here?  program B's DragAndDrop is true, and dragging and dropping files into the window works fine (I have tried sending a WM_DROPFILES message as well without success), and program B can open files just fine with my open file dialog, but this command has an issue saying it cannot find the file.

Comment: Are those the exact paths that you are using in your code? Or is the file system redirectory messing with you? Are there spaces in your command line argument? How are you detecting errors?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan No those are not the exact paths I am using, but I'd like it to work for any path (actual path I am testing is something like "C:\\Users\\Paul\\Desktop\\MyFolder\\MyFile.txt").  Yes there are spaces in the command line argument as a folder name has a space in it, hence my quotations.  Program B has a try/catch block, but it doesn't really give me any information.  Maybe I should be looking more into program B.

Comment: Windows APIs don't raise exceptions. try/catch won't do any good. You need to check for errors the right way. Check the return value of CreateProcess, as described in the documentation. What happens if you invoke the executable passing a parameter from a command window, cmd.exe? If that works you'll know it is possible. Otherwise give up now.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan I looked all through the documentation and skipped over the return value, I feel like a noob.  When I try a command such as "C:\ProgramB.exe" "C:\MyFile.txt" I have the same issue.  No wonder this bug wasn't fixed over the years!  Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You state in a comment that when you execute

```
"C:\ProgramB.exe" "C:\MyFile.txt"
```

from a command prompt, the program starts, but does not open your file. This means that the executable does not support passing a file name as an argument. This explains why your call to `CreateProcess` fails. It is doing exactly the same as the command interpretor cmd.exe. If it fails for one, it will fail for the other.

It looks like what you are attempting may not be possible.

You also said that you sent a `WM_DROPFILES` to the process. That's not something that you can do just like that. If the application does support drag and drop, then you'll be able to automate file opening, but it's more involved than sending a `WM_DROPFILES` from a different process. The first step is to confirm whether or not the application can even accept drag/drop performed interactively.

Comment: Im sure that program B can accept drag and drop, but it is very complicated to act like windows is sending a PostMessage with WM_DROPFILES so I gave up on that approach.  Do you have any suggestions on what, if any, better approaches exist?  I know it would be a lot easier to always load from a specific location but I'd really like to tell program B where to get the file from.

Comment: Passing a filename by command-line argument is very different than passing a filename by drag&drop.  If ProgramB is not coded to support command-line arguments then you are SOL. You have no choice but to run it without any arguments and then simulate the `WM_DROPFILES` window message (if you are having trouble doing that, then ask another question about it and show that code). Unless the app supports the `IDropTarget` interface, would would be an ideal alternative.

Comment: @Paul Sorry, I did not see your comment until now. I think Remy is right, faking drag/drop is worthy of a new question, if you can't work it out from websearch. I'm sure Raymond Chen wrote some articles about that. Yup, here it is: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2008/07/24/8768095.aspx